# Have there been efforts to write every statement (eg. axiom, postulate, result, theorem) in a standardised language?

Tags: logic, terminology, math-history

In the same vein/spirit as the UIPAC books for standardising systematic names and formulae of chemicals, the SI units for units of physical measurements, or the INN for generic drug names, have there been efforts to write every statement in mathematics (eg. axiom, postulate, result, theorem) in a standardised language? This standardised language might be a formal logic like those touched upon in mathematical logic textbooks or monographs, or it might simply be a set of standardised terms or statements in a natural language like English. (**I'd like to emphasise that a standardisation effort need not necessarily be one in a formal language.**)  I'd like to know if there existed, or there exists currently, a consortium, an organisation, an initiative etc. like this.. I tried searching for this on google but couldn't find one so far...

Ermm, do put aside the debate on whether such an effort is desirable or not.. I just like to know if there is/was such an effort, not whether it is a good/bad thing..

I've come across TPTP.org, but not sure if this is the largest/most well-known/most followed/most active effort so far in mathematics.. Do let me know if there's any better..

Comment: No Consortium, but the Project was already proposed (and more or less done) by [Giuseppe Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano). See [Formulario mathematico (1st ed. 1894)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulario_mathematico)

Comment: Thank you for comment.. But is there a more modern/recent case, with more widespread adoption/following?

Comment: The efforts of Bourbaki or Russel&Whitehead might be among the closest things to what you're talking about in terms of goals. And libraries of formalized mathematics such as Metamath's or Mizar's or Lean's might look similar, too; but their goals are not "widespread adoption" in the sense I think you mean. There may not be a great modern example for you, but I could be wrong/ignorant of some effort that's just not very popular.